# Listing current directory does not contain copied file

Tags: c#

After copying a file using File.Copy, current directory listing does not contain the copied file:

```
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the file to copy");
source = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter a name for the new file:");
string target = Console.ReadLine();
File.Copy(source, target);
Console.WriteLine("\n\nNew listing:");
foreach (var file in files)
       Console.WriteLine(file);
```

Answer (score 6):

`files` won't get updated until you call `files = Directory.GetFiles(path);` again.

It is an array that is filled from the call to `GetFiles`, not a link to the directory itself.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this:

```
    string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the file to copy");
source = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter a name for the new file:");
string target = Console.ReadLine();
File.Copy(source, target);
Console.WriteLine("\n\nNew listing:");

files = Directory.GetFiles(path); //this added

foreach (var file in files)
       Console.WriteLine(file);
```

Comment: Why call `Directory.GetFiles` twice?

Comment: @mjwills To get a new list of files.  OP is asking why the file list doesn't include a file they copied *after* getting a file list, so they would *have* to get files twice.  That said, this was already posted 10 minutes before this answer so there's no value here.